# How to set fixed colorbar values for jet colormap?

Tags: plotting, color

I want to use the jet color function in Mathematica, and the jet color function is defined as

```mathematica
jet[u_?NumericQ]:=Blend[{{0,RGBColor[0,0,9/16]},{1/9,Blue},{23/63,Cyan},{13/21,Yellow},{47/63,Orange},{55/63,Red},{1,RGBColor[1/2,0,0]}},u]/;0<=u<=1
```

which is from the question: [Custom ColorFunction/ColorData in ArrayPlot (and similar functions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753508/custom-colorfunction-colordata-in-arrayplot-and-similar-functions/9321152#9321152)

When I use jet to plot, I found that Mathematica will automatically use the maximum and minimum as the data range, there are [solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202516/how-to-set-color-range-for-contourplots) to rescale the colordata for the default colormap in Mathematica, but I can't use these methods to set the range for jet colormap. Here is a minimum example:
The default colormap's range could be set as

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x]*Cos[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap", 
     Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {-1, 1}}]]
```

[image]

and if I use jet colorfunction

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x]*Cos[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> jet, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {-1, 1}}]]
```

the data range is not correct
[image]

Comment: `ColorFunctionScaling -> True` ?

Comment: This can only change the data range for the barlegend but the density plot range will not chang

Comment: You already knew what to do in your first snippet; making the replacement with my  `jet[]` function should have been straightforward: `DensityPlot[Sin[x]*Cos[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> (jet[Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {-1, 1}}]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself after rereading the other questions:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x]*Cos[y]*0.3, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> (jet[Rescale[#, {-3, 3}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {-3, 3}}]]
```

[image]